# How do I get an historic view of the inflation votes?

Tags: inflation, ledger, history

Specifically, I'm interested in knowing what the state of inflation votes were at an arbitrary historic timestamp.  I can run the ledger backward to figure balances, but I'm not sure how I'd figure out previous votes if someone changes their vote.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the historical inflation votes data you need to run a [Horizon](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon) node with `CATCHUP_COMPLETE` parameter set to `true`.

Once a fully synced instance is ready, you will be able to query `history_effects` table which contains all ledger effects. Inflation destination is set by [`SET_OPTIONS` operation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/operation.html#set-options) that yields `SIGNER_UPDATED` effect despite the fact that official documentation mentions [`Account Home Domain Updated` effect](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/effect.html#effect-types). Here is a [bug description](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/252).

Therefore in your case an SQL statement that retrieves all `inflation_dest` changes will look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM history_effects 
WHERE type=12 AND details->>'inflation_dest' IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY history_operation_id, order
```

Add a filter by date and aggregate results to get `inflation_dest` for all accounts at a given point in time.

Comment: So if I wanted to know how many votes were cast to wallet GAEXAMPLE as of 2017-11-17 at 00:00 UTC, I would first have to figure out which wallets were voting for GAEXAMPLE on that date, and then run a routine to figure out the balances of all of those voter wallets.  Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. There is another option, if you don't need a historical data. You can setup a Core node, periodically fetch the up-to-date information and store it somewhere. Query in that case will be much simpler, you don't need to build complex aggregation SQLs.